# Convert raster LST 1 km to 250m (R resample)

Tags: r, resampling

I have two files, where the NDVI is at 250m and the LST is at 1k, I want to use resample of R to convert the LST to 250m.

```
ndvi <- raster("MOD13Q1.A2014017.tif")   
lst <- raster("MOD11A2.A2014017.tif")  
LST250 <- resample(lst, ndvi, method="ngb", filename="lst_250.tif")
```

But I get the following error, they could help me

[image]

[Edit] Unfortunately, I have discovered that it is not possible to do a function with resample, apparently it can only be called once, otherwise it gives me the error I have shown

```
resample <- function(){  
    ndvi <- raster("MOD13Q1.A2014017.tif")  
    lst <- raster("MOD11A2.A2014017.tif")  
    LST250 <- resample(lst, ndvi, method="ngb", filename="lst_250.tif")  
}

resample()
```

Comment: Maybe you have opened another package with a function with the same name. Try with `raster::resample(...)`

Comment: @aldo_tapia yeah, I agree. A simple test works for me, and there's a *lot* of other packages that create `resample`: https://www.rdocumentation.org/search?q=resample

Comment: What you've done is written a function called `resample` that calls `resample` - which then find your `resample` function instead of the one in the `raster` package. So since your `resample` function has no arguments then it gives an error because your call in the function has some arguments. If you really want to call your function `resample` then you need to call the `raster` package function as `raster::resample(...etc...)`.

Comment: Yes, off course. Three points represents yours arguments, the aim of my comment was indicate how to call `resample()` to avoid confusion with others functions. Also, be careful with `writeRaster()` (same name in `raster` and `rasclass` package). If `resample()` doesn't work (as you say), use `projectRaster()`.